# How to get Information from new Objects

Tags: object, jlabel, generate

how can i get Information (like Locations, Name, Size, etc.) from new Objects.

```
public class Labelerzeugungklasse extends JLabel {

    public Labelerzeugungklasse(String name, int x, int y, ImageIcon icon) {
        new JLabel(name);
        this.setIcon(icon);
        this.setBounds(0, 0, 80, 60);
        this.setLocation(x, y);
        DragListener drag = new DragListener();
        this.addMouseListener(drag);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(drag);

    }

}


HintergrundRukkla.add(new Labelerzeugungklasse(LabelName, x, y, iiii));
```

Here i generate a new JLabel, but how can i get Information/Data from this Label after the generation.

Like: "generatedJLabel".getLocation();

Best Regards Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a handler that points to the new object:

```
Labelerzeugungklasse label = new Labelerzeugungklasse(LabelName, x, y, iiii);
```

Add the object, as you have in your code (I am assuming HintergrundRukkla is a Jframe):

```
HintergrundRukkla.add(label);
```

Since you now have a handler to the label, you can use it to call any method the Jlabel supports, like:

```
label.getText();
label.getIcon();
label.getHorizontalAlignment();
```

You can see the supported methods here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html
in the 'Method Summary' section

Comment: Yeah, but it will generate the Labels out of a Database. So i can not give alllll Labels Manually a spezific name

Comment: Ok, so create an array of objects(labels).

Comment: Jlabels[] labels = new Jlabels[number_of_labels];

Comment: and how can i get information out of an array JLabel ? (for example the location)

Comment: You will get information from each individual element of the array.
If 'labels' is an array of Jlabel objects, you can access for example the 3rd one using ' labels[2].getText(); '.
If you need to check every Jlabel in the array, you need to use a loop.